# How to pass an object from a fragment to an activity detail view using ViewModel(MVVM)?

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I'm using MVVM as architecture, how can I pass an object from a fragment(recycler + viewModel) to an activity(detail view + viewModel)?

This is the viewmodel for the fragment

```
class BuyViewModel : ViewModel() {
private lateinit var buys: MutableLiveData<List<Buy>>
private var buyRemote = BuyRemote()
private var buyRepository: BuyRepository = BuyRepository.getInstance(buyRemote)

fun getBuys(): LiveData<List<Buy>> {
    if(!::buys.isInitialized) {
        buys = MutableLiveData()
        buys = buyRepository.getBuys()
    }
    return buys
}

}
```

This is the Adapter for the fragment

```
class BuyAdapter(internal var context: Context,
             private var resource: Int,
             private var buyList: ArrayList<Buy>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BuyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return buyList.size
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        .inflate(resource, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val buy: Buy = buyList[position]
    val propertyImages: List<String> =
        buy.propertyImage.split(",")


    //Start DetailView Activity
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(context, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val intent = Intent(context, BuyDetailActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

`+++++++++++++++code removed for brevity+++++++++++++++++`

And finally this is the fragment

```
class BuyFragment : Fragment() {
companion object {
    fun newInstance() = BuyFragment()
}

private lateinit var viewModel: BuyViewModel
private val buyList = ArrayList<Buy>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BuyViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.getBuys().observe(this, Observer<List<Buy>> { buys ->
        buyList.addAll(buys)
        (rvBuy.adapter as BuyAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.buy_fragment, container, false)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    rvBuy.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    rvBuy.adapter = BuyAdapter(activity!!.applicationContext,
        R.layout.buy_card, buyList)
}
```

How can I implement this while respecting best practices. 
When the user click an item form the recycler view(fragment) it will pass an object "Buy" to an activity.
Should that activity uses a view model on its own? How?
Should the activity use the same viewmodel as the fragment recycler view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a shared view model that is tied to the activity between the fragments. 
Get the ViewModel in the fragments like so.

```
val sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

Then in the list fragment `onClick` class `sharedViewModel.onItemClicked(item)`

```
SharedViewModel {
    private val _selectedItem = MutableLiveData<T>()
    val selectedItem: LiveData<T> get() = _selectedItem

    fun onItemClick(item: T) {
        _selectedItem.value = item
    }
}
```

Then in the Detail Fragment

```
sharedViewModel.selectedItem.observe {
    detailViewModel.setItem(it)
}
```

Then in the detail view model load the item and display.

**UPDATE**

To access the shared view model from the activity get the view model:

```
val sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

Then observe the `selectedItem` LiveData as you would in a fragment.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a detail fragment but an activity. An activity host a tab of three fragments, each fragment display a list of item using a recyclerView, when I click on an item, it should pass the data(an object) to a detail view(an activity).

Comment: the click listener method is in the RecyclerView adapter class not in the fragment.

Comment: Pass the viewModel to the adapter.

Comment: is it best practice to do so? I mean doesn't it violate the MVVM principle? I'm very new to MVVM. Thanks for helping

Comment: No it doesn't MVVM says you talk down (ie call methods) and react up (observe). The adapter and the fragment/activity are both part of the view.

Comment: @Ge3ng Can you please show a demo of how we can pass the data from fragment to activity( a detailed activity which will be displayed after clicking on the list item) using view model